# copying range end xl down pasting different Wb

Tags: vba, variables, copy, paste

I've got a macro recorder code (with select and activate) that I'm trying to simplify. It currently looks like this:

```
Windows("Stambestand.xlsm").Activate
Range("AA2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ijking document.xlsm").Activate
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

As of recently I've started using variables and want to trim down the code. I'm thinking along these lines:

```
WbStambestand.WsStam.Range("AA2", Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy WbIjk.WsIjk.range("A1").paste

Workbooks("WbStambestand").Worksheets("WsStam").Range("AA2", Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
```

However, these don't function. I'm hoping you guys can help me along. Much appreciated.

FYI, these are my variables (they are declared). The Ijk ones are the paste destination.

```
Dim WbStambestand, WbIjk As Workbook 
Dim WsIjk, WsStam As Worksheet

Set WsIjk = ActiveSheet 
Set WbIjk = ActiveWorkbook
Set WsIjk = ActiveSheet
Set WbIjk = ActiveWorkbook
Set WbStambestand = Workbooks.Open(stam)
Set WsStam = WbStambestand.Worksheets("stambestand")
```

Comment: What I'd suggest is just don't trim down the code, it's fine the way it is any your "trimmed down" code on two long lines is too difficult to read to be worth it.

Comment: apparently the macro runes faster when it doesn't need to switch back and forth to select stuff all the time (im running it 15 times or something with a varying number of rows). Besides, I want to code as efficient as possible.
Regarding the length, I can use the space_ to split the line.

Comment: ah so you're not trying to just simplify it's length, you're looking for a more efficient method in terms of speed?

Comment: Yes, and I want to code in the best and most efficient way possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    Sub abc()
    Dim WbStambestand As Workbook
    Dim WbIjk As Workbook
    Dim WsIjk As Worksheet
    Dim WsStam As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim stam As String

    stam = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Stambestand.xlsm" ' path with complete file name with extension.
    Set WsIjk = ActiveSheet
    Set WbIjk = ThisWorkbook ' workbook which has current code
    Set WbStambestand = Workbooks.Open(stam)
    Set WsStam = WbStambestand.Worksheets("stambestand")

    LastRow = WsStam.Range("AA2").End(xlDown).Row
    WsStam.Range("AA2:AA" & LastRow).Copy WsIjk.Range("B3")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Should that be declared as a Range?

Comment: declare as Long

Comment: Oh sorry, so focused on the last 2 lines in my code.
Edit: as for the destination to paste. Why is WsIjk or WbIjk.WsIjk,Range("B3") not working? It shows object needed. (WbIjk is ijking.document.xlsm, WsIjk is worksheet in Wb)

Comment: declare WbIjk  as workbook and WsIjk as worksheet. please check http://codevba.com/excel/set_workbook.htm#.WYRL41UjHIU

Comment: I think I've done that (The macro is being run in the active wb).

`Dim WbStambestand, WbIjk As Workbook
Dim WsIjk, WsStam As Worksheet
Set WsIjk = ActiveSheet
Set WbIjk = ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: Thanks a lot Maddy, I will check it out on monday and give feedback. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Hi Maddy, that did the trick. I think it was the adding of :AA" after Range("AA2:") (or what we had before).

Comment: Correct `:AA` was missing before